# What is the Chinese translation for "endure and move on"?

Tags: translation, word-choice, characters, word-requests

I've been trying to get the Chinese word with meaning of the phrase

> endure and move on.

It has something to do with a break up with a girlfriend and wanting to endure it and move on. I've tried googling it and found the following. (This is also how I found this website.) I just want to know if I got the right translation. Here's what I found:

> 忍和想开

Here's my questions: 1. Is this the right right translation? 2. Do I really need to put the 和 ("and") in the middle or is there no need for that?

---

To be honest, I'll have it tattooed in my arm. That's why I'm trying to keep it as short as possible, but of course I want to have the correct message of the tattoo. Also, my father is pure Chinese but he was naturalized in our country since 1980's. That's why I want to have it in Chinese characters. (It will add more meaning to the tattoo.) Sadly, I can no longer speak to him and that's why I have to ask this question here, and I didn't study in a Chinese school.

Comment: If it's the whole thing you want to translate -- 1. it's grammatical, but sounds non-native; 2. yes, you need 和 in the middle. But there's some subtle difference between the English and Chinese phrases, if I didn't get it wrong, "endure and move on" means "bear the pain and continue the life"; but 想开 means "let go", once you 想开, you don't have to bear any pain, you just get over the pain, so it means you don't have to 忍 any more. "忍和想开" doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: That was 6 years ago. What did you finally chose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often better to provide the whole English sentence for translation. As divergent as the two language can go, a phrase-to-phrase translation is often less than pragmatic.

What I can get is "忍受悲伤, 继续前行". But as Stan said, if you move on, you usually put away your sorrows, or 抛却悲伤 instead.

There is a phrase from classical Chinese, "隐忍以行". It is an exact structural match to your phrase. However, it implies endurance for a greater cause than love.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to provide some context.

「節哀順變」 is very close to literally "endure and move on", but you are most likely to hear this in a funeral.

For break up, use 「天涯何處無芳草」 (which means there are always someone somewhere).

Comment: Is "funnel" supposed to be "funeral"?

Comment: Well spot. Revised accordingly.

Comment: 天涯何處無芳草  -- this would have to be tattooed on his thigh?

Answer (score 0):

忍过了，你的人生还得继续
"忍和想开" seem wired, "and" can translate as "然后"  “忍忍，然后想开点"is better